# mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) not working for QComboBox in Qt

Tags: qt

Ok, so I implemented the function following function:

`CommandInput` is a class which inherits the `class QComboBox`.

```
void CommandInput::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Proposed drop " << event->mimeData()->formats();
    event->acceptProposedAction();
}
```

**and it is working fine.**

But the problem is my following function is not working , in fact when I click mouse button, nothing gets printed, Why is that?

```
void CommandInput::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    qDebug()<<"X IS"<<e->pos().x();
}
```

Comment: Probably something else inside the combobox accepts that event.

Comment: @thuga May be its child lineEdit accepts that, so how to solve that problem?

Comment: You can [install an event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) on it. If you're unsure which widget it is, you can install an event filter on your `QApplication` object and debug for mouse press events to see which object is the last one to receive it.